# What is an example of numbers that when used for a Gaussian pulse, would result in a rotation about the x axis?

Tags: programming, qiskit, openpulse

For the playing of a Gaussian pulse, what is an example of numbers that could be plugged in for duration, amp, and sigma that would result in the pulse rotating something about the x axis?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
with pulse.build(backend, name='hadamard') as h_q0:
    pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=1200, amp=0.1409018732350299, sigma=32), pulse.drive_channel(0))
```

Comment: Maybe the documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/05_pulse_gates.html) helps.

Comment: Does it not depend on the backend?